# Depth First Search in Python

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search

I'm having problems in implementing search algorithms in Python. I need a generic depth first search code which can return the path from the start state to end state.

Comment: [this page might help you](http://google.com)

Comment: Just as a heads up, it sounds like the [CS188 guys](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/sp12/projects/search/search.html) are pretty good about seeing if you've just taken code from somewhere else and it sounds like they take it pretty seriously: "If you do, we will pursue the strongest consequences available to us."  [You may not be aware that people with sufficient reputation can see deleted questions.]  It's probably easier to try to learn how DFS works and implement it yourself than to take one from somewhere and try to disguise it.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i do not mean to copy paste. but got so stumped in implementing any type of search let alone dfs though i think i got a good grasp on the concept of it. can you point where i can learn implementing depth first search, so that i can begin to understand how to tackle this, but where it is given simple (i mean i bought the book and still got nothing). Perhaps if you could point me out the logical steps for such a problem

Answer (score 4):

Start with this [essay](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) on implementing Graphs in Python and then understand that DFS may use a stack to pop in and pop out nodes of the graph. Having this idea may help you proceed with implementing DFS in Python. And if you have specific questions, please post here and folks are ready to help.

Comment: @l4mpi I guess you meant for favoretti link.

Comment: nice essay. i only glanced over it but +1

Answer (score 2):

You can find a detailed implementation explanation [at literateprograms.org](http://en.literateprograms.org/Depth-first_search_%28Python%29).

(Actually, it's pretty much the first Google hit, trying that before posting questions on SO might help next time)

Answer (score 1):

Use the adjacency list representation to implement the graph. Code to implement it is as follows. (this code is specific if you use Python to read a text file on graph and implement the adjecency list)

(Python 3.3)

```
def ajlist(nameofgraph,start,goal):

x=input("enter the name of the file you want to implement adjecency list: ")##file.txt##
text_file=open(x,"r")
nameofgraph={}##use a dictionary##
for line in text_file:
   (vertex,val)=line.split()
   if vertex not in nameofgraph:
      nameofgraph[vertex]=set9[val])
   else:
      nameofgraph.get[key].add(val)
stack=[(stack,[start])]
while stack:
   (vertex,path)=stack.pop()
   for next in graph[vertex]-set(path):
      if next==goal:
         yield (path+[next])
      else:
         stack.append((next,path+[next]))
```

When you want to run this use this syntax `list(DFS(nameofgraph,start,goal))`

Above is the easiest way of doing DFS and find the path in graph. If you have implemented a graph in python then you do not need the (input) function. Then you have to do is take away the implementing adjecency list part and use the real traversal part.